# In Vue, what is the purpose of v-model.trim

Tags: vuejs2, trim

I am new to Vue and have learned `v-model` directive.
To test what `v-model.trim` does I wrote the following code.

```
<template>
<p>Hello {{ myName }}</p>
<form>Name: <input type="text" v-model.trim="myName"/></form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      myName: "",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

When I typed in `"      B         o         b"` the output was `"B o b"`. However, I found out that even when I don't use `v-model.trim` and just use `v-model` as follows

```
<template>
<p>Hello {{ myName }}</p>
<form>Name: <input type="text" v-model="myName"/></form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      myName: "",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

it gives the exact same output.
What is the purpose of `.trim`?

Comment: In Javascript, .trim() is a String method to remove the spaces at the beginning and at the end of a string, so the same behavior is applied to v-model

Comment: Hi, I want to know why would I use .trim when it trims spaces without .trim?

Comment: It won't trim automatically, you did explicitly by using `v-mode.trim`

Comment: If you're looking for spaces in `view(html)`, browser [ignores](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk018feh5xRgUqW4OULHe5232BdNvpA%3A1612198533556&ei=hTIYYNK-IenTz7sPvJ2-yAY&q=why+empty+spaces+ignored+in+html&oq=why+empty+spaces+ignored+in+html&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwAzoFCAAQzQI6BggAEBYQHjoECCEQClC3FljUSmDgTGgBcAJ4AYABwwKIAZ8SkgEHMy43LjIuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiSlZnHk8nuAhXp6XMBHbyOD2kQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) the white spaces, try to check in the console.

Comment: Maybe my wording was poor, I edited and added another example which uses v-model without .trim. This does the exact same thing and I want to ask if v-model does the job what is the purpose of .trim?

Answer (score 10):

Per the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim)

> If you want whitespace from user input to be trimmed automatically, you can add the trim modifier to your v-model-managed inputs

`v-model.trim="msg"` is equal to doing `msg = msg.trim()` which removes white spaces before/after input.

Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pjgnyy) if you still have any doubts.

If you're looking for spaces in `view(html)`, browser [ignores](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk018feh5xRgUqW4OULHe5232BdNvpA%3A1612198533556&ei=hTIYYNK-IenTz7sPvJ2-yAY&q=why+empty+spaces+ignored+in+html&oq=why+empty+spaces+ignored+in+html&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoHCAAQRxCwAzoFCAAQzQI6BggAEBYQHjoECCEQClC3FljUSmDgTGgBcAJ4AYABwwKIAZ8SkgEHMy43LjIuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiSlZnHk8nuAhXp6XMBHbyOD2kQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) the white spaces, try to check in the console.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, .trim() is a String method to remove the spaces at the beginning and at the end of a string, so the same behavior is applied to v-model

Answer (score 0):

It trims spacing from the beginning and end of strings.

So if you imagine you have an email input using model binding, and the user types their email with the a space after, that’s not going to be a valid email address. So the `trim` modifier truncates the spacing at the end.

Answer (score 0):

trim() is a String method to remove the spaces at the beginning and at the end of a string, so the same behavior is applied to v-model